# REST call to compute the request

Tags: java, spring, rest

Which REST verb should I use to compute my request? `POST` or `PUT`.
For example:

**Request:**

```
{
  start:[
    "1",
     "2"
  ], 
    end: [
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  new:[
   "3"
  ],
  stayed: [
   "2"
  ],
  gone: [
   "1"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what exactly is being done on the server to produce this response?

Comment: Just compute the result based on request. There is no call to database or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since your request is [nullipotent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nullipotent), you should use `GET`. You can send the data as a JSON query parameter.

[Here is a helpful Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters) about how to do generate a URL containing a query parameter.

Comment: Yes, but it is not recommended, you can send it in the URL if you can change the client.

Comment: How would I send the payload in a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more info about what you're doing/intending to do to help us out.  That being said, when using REST calls, GET, PUT, POST, and DELETE perform the basic CRUD operations.  GET returns a value, PUT updates an existing value, POST creates a new value, and DELETE deletes a value.  This applies to any format (XML, JSON, etc).  For adding new values to a server, use POST if the value doesn't already exist on the server and PUT if it does but you want to update its value(s).  I hope this helps.  If you need more help, please provide more background info on what you're trying to do.